# How to set root directory for resolving absolute paths in esbuild?

Tags: esbuild

import {validateEmail} from "/util/util.js";

When I try to bundle a js file containing many such imports, esbuild cannot resolve the path.

When opened in a browser, this resolves to {webroot}/util/utij.js, but when I try to bundle it on windows, esbuild looks for the file in the root of the C drive and fails to find the file.

Is there a way to set the path that would be used as root when resolving an absolute path?

I tried actually moving the project to the root of the drive and then it works, as well as changing the import to "../../util/util.js", but it would be easier if I could just set the root directory with a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer replied to me [over on github](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/2998).

The root directory can be set by creating a tsconfig.json and using the option --tsconfig="path to config". In the config file, you can remap the root path "/" to anything, including the current working directory.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "/*": [
        "./*"     <------- Remap "/" to "./"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```